# mysql where columnname in (function(a value)) not working

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have a strange situation here with the mysql query:
 When the `WHERE unterkategorie IN (children_csv(1))` is used there is no result. 
     Second `"WHERE unterkategorie IN (11,12,13,28,29,32,14,15,16,30,31,33,34,35)"` is fetching records when I substitute function name with the results of the function when executed separately

the full query is:

```
    SELECT k.name category_name,
       p.unterkategorie,
       p.artikelnummer,
       p.hauptkategorie,
       p.id,
       p.name product_name,
       p.preis,
       p.sortierung,
       p.verpackungseinheit
FROM produkte p, kategorie k
WHERE unterkategorie IN (children_csv(1))
WHERE unterkategorie IN (11,12,13,28,29,32,14,15,16,30,31,33,34,35) 
AND p.unterkategorie = k.id
ORDER BY unterkategorie, p.sortierung
```

Following is the function definition

```
delimiter //
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `children_csv`(child int)RETURNS varchar(1000) CHARSET utf8
    BEGIN
    declare return_value varchar(1000);
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Level SEPARATOR ',')childrens into return_value FROM (
                                SELECT @Ids := (
                                    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`id` SEPARATOR ',')
                                    FROM `kategorie`
                                    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`parent`, @Ids)
                                    ORDER BY parent, sortierung

                                ) Level
                                FROM `kategorie`
                                JOIN (SELECT @Ids := child) temp1
                                WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`parent`, @Ids)

                             ) temp2;

        RETURN return_value;
    END;
    //
    delimiter ;
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly so it is easier to read.

Comment: I think format is ok now

Answer (score 0):

Your function is returning a single value, a string.  It is not returning a a list of values (because MySQL functions do not do that).  If you want to use the function directly, you can use `find_in_set()`:

```
WHERE find_in_set(unterkategorie, children_csv(1))
```

I will caution you that MySQL cannot use an index on `unterkategorie`, so this might be slower.

If you want a faster query, then you can construct a query as a string (called dynamic SQL) and use `prepare` and `exec` to run it.

If you are coming from another programming language, you need to learn that functions are not the route to better performance in SQL.  Moving the logic into a function generally does not help performance.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. It solved my problem. And I appreciate your explanations.